# Find Children In Parent in Jquery

Tags: jquery, find, children

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 `C#` and `jQuery`. On my web form I have one main div(`divMain`). Inside this div some children are created dynamically namely `divValue0,divValue1....divValuen`. I want to access each div whose `id` starts with `divValue`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you want to find all `div` elements whose `id` starts with "divValue" that are children of `divMain`. If that's right then something like this should work:

```
var yourDivs = $("#divMain").children("div[id^='divValue']");
```

It uses an "[attribute starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector to match any element with an `id` value starting with "divValue". The [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method returns all of the children of the selected element, but if you wanted descendants further down the DOM, you'll have to use `find` instead.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)